# Firebase Analytics throws errors on building in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-analytics

I am trying to implement analytics by firebase, I have imported the FirebaseAnalytics pod in my class, but when I try to use any of it's methods, there are errors on xcode build, please help me resolve this issue, I tried most of the solutions adding the $(inherited), adding -Objc, but none of them seem to work, please point me to right solution

**Implementation**

```
import FirebaseAnalytics

class PerformanceHandler {
   func recordCustomEvent(name: String, attributes: [String: Any]) {
       Analytics.logEvent(name, parameters: attributes)
   }
}
```

**Error**

[image]

[image]

I am on **Xcode 14** and the latest version of cocoapods **1.11.3**.

**Podfile** (Sorry wouldn't be able to add the entire podfile, here is a gist of it)

```
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'FirebasePerformance'
```

The PerformanceHandler class mentioned above is part of a custom pod, the code is split into respective Pods following a modular architecture.

Comment: Can you share your podfile?

Comment: What about podfile.lock? Which version of Firebase u are using?

Comment: @DmytroYashchenko The version of firebase is  Firebase (10.0.0)